# Mapping sub domains in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat8

My webapps directory in Tomcat currently looks like this.

```
webapps/
    |
    -CR/
    |
    -HW/
    |
    -SWC/
```

I have the webapps folder with three subfolder, CR, HW and SWC

I want `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` to go to the folder SWC. So I have added the following in my `server.xml` and it works as expected.

```
<Host name="mydomain.com" appBase="webapps/SWC" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>mydomain.com</Alias>
    <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/SWC"/>
</Host>

<Host name="www.mydomain.com" appBase="webapps/SWC" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>www.mydomain.com</Alias>
    <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/SWC"/>
</Host>
```

The two other contexts I like to have mapped as follows:

```
Context                   Sub domain
HW                        www.mydomain.com/HW and mydomain.com/HW
CR                        www.mydomain.com/CR and mydomain.com/CR
```

Best would be to have some default setup that everything else just follows the pattern `webapps/[folder]` mapped as `mydomain.com/[folder]` and `www.mydomain.com/[folder]`. I have `<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">` which I thought would take care of routing the sub domains.

Currently the sub domains are not working. How should I configure this to work?

Comment: In web applications, you're not really dealing directly with folders but with URLs (though an URL might point to a folder) The resources (html pages, files, images) within the folders are still accessible so I don't understand what the problem here is.

Comment: For instance if I enter www.mydomain.com/CR it doesn't work. I won't give me a web page.

Comment: What web page? Did you implement the doGet method? (I assume you're using a servlet)

Comment: Of course, the name attribute is usually set to localhost in server.xml and everything else should be processed by your servlet (you may also need a web.xml although with Tomcat8, all configuration can be achieved using annotations).